# Can't access special key in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

when I use following code

```
foreach($admin_info as $key => $val)
{
echo $key."   ".$val."\n";
}
```

I will get true result:

```
id 1
username Moein7tl
password 0937afa17f4dc08f3c0e5dc908158370ce64df86
mail moein7tl@gmail.com
added_time 
super_admin 
last_time 
last_ip 
see_user_per 1
change_user_per 1
see_people_per 1
change_people_per 1
add_people_per 1
remove_people_per 1
see_album_per 1
add_album_per 1
change_album_per 1
remove_album_per 1
see_music_per 1
add_music_per 1
change_music_per 1
remove_music_per 1
admin_per 1
yahoo_per 1
status_per 1
pm_per 1
ip_blocking_per 1
```

but when I use `echo ($admin_info['id']);` or with other keys, it will make an error and no result will be shown.
where is problem?
--edit
`var_dump($admin_info);` will return

```
object(stdClass)#21 (27) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(8) "Moein7tl" ["password"]=> string(40) "0937afa17f4dc08f3c0e5dc908158370ce64df86" ["mail"]=> string(18) "moein7tl@gmail.com" ["added_time"]=> NULL ["super_admin"]=> string(0) "" ["last_time"]=> NULL ["last_ip"]=> NULL ["see_user_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["change_user_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["see_people_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["change_people_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["add_people_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["remove_people_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["see_album_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["add_album_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["change_album_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["remove_album_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["see_music_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["add_music_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["change_music_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["remove_music_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["admin_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["yahoo_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["status_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["pm_per"]=> string(1) "1" ["ip_blocking_per"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what is the error?

Comment: Could you tell us more about this error? What is displayed when you use `echo get_class($admin_info)`?

Comment: try print_r($admin_info['id']) at the place where u call the echo.. and tell us the result.. or show full code..

Comment: I would guess that `$admin_info` is an object and not an array (i.e.: stdClass is traversable so `foreach` would work there). Try using `$admin_info->id` instead.

Comment: Try doing var_dump($admin_info); - this will tell you how your array/object is built and it would be a lot easier to identify the problem, when you know exactly what you are working with.

Comment: it will return object(stdClass)#21 (27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem,CodeIgniter will return database result as Object.
So I should do it like that `$admin_info->id` and it solves problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$admin_info->password`, this should work as `$admin_info` seems to be an object of `stdClass`.

Answer (score -3):

Your logic is correct, but you may try using echo $admin_info['id']; without the Parenthesis.

Comment: When you don't answer the question, use comments. Or do you think removing the parenthesis will solve the problem?

Comment: thats not an error .. echo can also be used like that.. refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php